# C++/SDL angle from one object to another

Tags: c++, math, sdl

I want to rotate a 2-D image in the direction to where I click, to all quadrants. To do this, I need to calculate the angle relative to the object. I need 2 vectors.

I have tried to do this: one vector would be the "click" point, the other would be an "imaginary" horizontal vector departing from the object with the same X as the "click" point but with the Y of the object. That would serve as the second vector to where I would calculate the angle from the object.

I have made a test program with 3 objects to see if I can get those angles. `b6` is the object, `b7` is a "click point" approximately 45º from `b6`, and `b8` is another "click point" approximately 135º from `b6`.

This is the code I'm using:

```
#define PI 3.14159265

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

   Button b6(100,100); 
   Button b7(150,50);
   Button b8(150,150);

   int dot1 = b7.getX() * b7.getX() + b7.getY() * b6.getY();
   int det1 = b7.getX() * b6.getY() - b7.getY() * b7.getX();
   double angle1 = atan2(det1,dot1)* 180/PI;

   int dot2 = b8.getX() * b8.getX() + b8.getY() * b6.getY();   
   int det2 = b8.getX() * b6.getY() - b8.getY() * b8.getX();
   double angle2 = atan2(det2,dot2)* 180/PI;
}
```

The results don't correspond to the actual position of `b7` and `b8`. `angle1` is 15.25, and `angle2` is -11.31.

I'm a novice in this, and I don't know if what I'm doing is a total mess. Can anyone help me compute these angles?

Comment: It's somewhat unclear to me exactly what you expected to accomplish by multiplying X and Y coordinates against in each other, in seemingly random pairings. If I wanted to know the distance between two cartesian coordinates (as a precursor to figuring out their relative angle from the axis), the mathematical operation I would expect to use would be subtraction.

Comment: Your example should be reduced, the `Button` type is completely unnecessary and just obfuscates things. Also, there is no relation to SDL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Sam already wrote in comment – not clear, what OP wants to achieve with `dot` and `det`. It sounds a bit like dot product but it's not necessary here.

A vector from one point to the other is simply the subtraction of points (point vectors).

Subtraction of point vectors is simply the subtraction of vector components.

Using the components of these vectors in `atan2()` provides the slope of these vectors:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

const double Pi = 3.14159265;

struct Vec2 {
  const double x, y;
  Vec2(double x, double y): x(x), y(y) { }
  ~Vec2() = default;
  Vec2(const Vec2&) = default;
  Vec2& operator=(const Vec2&) = delete;
};

int main()
{
  const Vec2 b6(100, 100);
  const Vec2 b7(150, 50);
  const Vec2 b8(150, 150);
  // vector b6->b7
  const Vec2 b67(b7.x - b6.x, b7.y - b6.y);
  // vector b6->b8
  const Vec2 b68(b8.x - b6.x, b8.y - b6.y);
  // slope b67
  const double angle1 = atan2(b67.y, b67.x) * 180 / Pi;
  // slope b68
  const double angle2 = atan2(b68.y, b68.x) * 180 / Pi;
  // output
  std::cout
    << "angle1: " << angle1 << '\n'
    << "angle2: " << angle2 << '\n';
  // done
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
angle1: -45
angle2: 45
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8fc9db061e855384)</kbd>

A Sketch of the `Vec2` instances:

[image: A Sketch of the Vec2 instances]

Comment: Thanks Scheff. Using your code, im getting accurate angles. However, the thing is, i need the results to be from 0 to 360. Your code only gives results from 0 to 180 (starting from 90), and worst the upper quadrants start anti-clockwise. I have tried to tweak the code, but i havent been able to get something that i could work with it. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: @Dar-kol This might depend of where (0, 0) is located. In OpenGL (as usual in mathematics), it's in the lower left corner. In 2D graphics, it's usually in the upper left corner. In the latter case, it works as well but yields vertically mirrored results. E.g. positive rotation is clock-wise (instead of counter-clockwise as usual in math and OpenGL).

Comment: @Dar-kol Concerning the angle: According to doc. of [`std::atan2()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/atan2) _If no errors occur, the arc tangent of y/x (arctan(y, x)) in the range (-π , +π] radians, is returned._ If you prefer the range [0, 360], you could transform the returned result of `atan2()` e.g. by `fmod(angle + 2 * Pi, 2 * Pi)`. Btw. I'm wondering a bit why you insist in positive angles. For most operations concerning angles or circles, 270° makes no difference to -90° (but, of course, it depends on how angle shall be used in further processing).

Comment: I have swapped the objects in the Vec2 operations. Now the object rotates to where i clicked. Well, still not perfect because it want it to move toward the click point, and it still isnt perfect, but im getting closer and thats another question.